# How do i cast A to object to class A when B can typcast to A?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, implicit-conversion

Basically i want to do this. aa causes a bad cast exception.
NOTE: o can be ANYTHING. It may not be B, it can be C, D, E, F etc. But this should work as long as o is a class that can typecast into A (B is such a class. It uses an implicit operator overload)

```
        var b = (B)"sz";
        var a = (A)b;
        object o = b;
        var aa = (A)o;
```

Comment: This example code would be more readable if you replaced the `var` keyword with the actual inferred types.

Comment: Voted to close, as this is a second attempt to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486791/how-do-i-cast-an-object-to-a-string-when-object-is-not-a-string/2486815#2486815 except now there is even less contextual information.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: I feel the string part confuses people and what i am doing above is what i am doing in code.

Comment: However, the original question concerns a specific case that's probably best solved without casts entirely, whereas this question highlights the tricky distinction between casts+conversions.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne - the reason the specific case is best solved without casts is precisely *because* of the difference between the two. It's the same question.

Comment: @Daniel: In both cases, the solution revolves around casts vs. conversions.  However, the questions are distinct: were I to look for information on this, say, via google, then the two questions seem approachable from entirely different angles: one Q is about casts vs. conversions, and the other is about using them in a particular fashion.  In any case it doesn't look to me like this second question is redundant from the point of view of a novice, which is kind of the point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried doing the following?

```
[...]
var ee = (A)(B)o;
```

The reason this will work and your code doesn't is that such explicit casts are *statically* compiled.  In other words, when you say `(A)o` the compiler looks for an explicit cast from **object** to `A` and doesn't find one.  However, it does determine that `A` is a subclass of object, so the cast may be viable at runtime - and it inserts an attempt to runtime down-cast the instance into a field of type `A`.  Such runtime casts have nothing to do with explicit and/or implicit conversions; these simply follow the built-in type hierarchy rules.

Another example:

```
object o = 1.0;
int i = (int)o; //throws InvalidCastException - even though (int)1.0 is OK.
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why operator overloads wont work. I'm likely to accept this.

Comment: Right. It is exactly the same as overload resolution. If you say "ob = giraffe" and you have overloaded methods M(object) and M(Animal) then M(ob) chooses the object overload at compile time no matter what ob is at runtime. The compiler chooses the "object to A" conversion operator over the "B to A" conversion operator because that's what's known at compile time. That's what you get for having a statically typed language; if you want it to be dynamically typed, then (1) use a dynamically typed language, or (2) use the dynamic keyword in C# 4.